# login fails with hazelcast mancenter in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, serialization, authentication, hazelcast

I deployed hazelcast 3.2.4 into a tomcat 7.0.54 and added the mancenter war also (the tomcat is a hazelcast client). first there was a problem with com.hazelcast.webmonitor.repositories.SerializationHelper due to hazelcast-3.2.4.jar being in tomcat/server/lib and in the mancenter.war. This was solved by removing the jar from mancenter.war. Then it looked all good at first, login worked, admin users could be created. But after a tomcat restart logins do not work anymore (wrong username) and no exceptions throws anywhere. Seems there is a problem with ~/mancenter3/user.xx serialized settings? When those are removed and tomcat restarted, login works again, until...

I didn't like to alter the mancenter.war - with previous versions this setup worked perfectly (hazelcast 3.1). But the hazelcast jar must be in tomcat server level since I have a global component there shared by some webapps.

Any help on this is much appreciated, even tweaking the authentication of mancenter to tomcat users would be ok, I'm not sure how to configure that in mancenter spring security, or if that is possible at all... But if it's a serialization problem, other issues will probably arise...

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: unfortunately not. checked for duplicate libraries or such, no luck. waiting for 3.3 release now.